# Special characters being shown as text instead of processed as HTML

Tags: html, mysql

I have tried to search for the answer to my question without any luck.

I have entered special characters in Phpmyadmin as their HTML encodings, e.g. an e with acute accent is entered like this:

```
&eacute;
```

But on my website it is being rendered as text, so instead of the e with acute accent I see the HTML encoding. It does not get processed as HTML:

```
J'ai souvent &eacute;t&eacute; appel&eacute; peu r&eacute;aliste.
```

Here is the link: http://www.personality-types.org/fr/

Why does this happen and how can I get it to be processed as html?

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: you probably double-encoded somewhere, so it's going into your html as `&amp;eacute;`,

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Looking at the source code I see that you are correct. So how do I avoid the double encoding? The sql files I am uploading to Phpmyadmin do not have this double encoding, and when I browse the variables in Phpmyadmin I also do not see this double encoding, so it seems to be happening in the browser upon retrieving the information from the database (?).

Comment: no idea. somewhere you've probably got an `htmlspecialchars()` call or whatever. phpmyadmin couldn't care less about html. it's just text as far as it's concerned and would not be doing encoding like that behind your back.

Comment: All right - thank you for your help, most appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

your page has charsert utf-8 wich is a good thing, but your page has to be saved in utf-8, your connection has to be set in utf-8, and your database has also to be set in utf-8. This way, no probleme concerning characters.
If you type your texte directly in phpmyadmin, feel free to type all accents without trying to convert it.